# Android AOP/IOC applicated

Tags: java, android, inversion-of-control, aop

I've recently thought about how it should be done in better way

This is sample from default usage of Android SDK

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

It's kind of annoying, that we have to call manually `super.onCreate` or the application will throw an Exception

Is there any way, how it could be applicated better, with annotations or some kind of AOP hook?

I'd like to have

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    @OnCreate // Replaces super.onCreate call
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    }

}
```

or even better

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    }

}
```

Could this be possible ?

Comment: Having to call through to `super` is a Java thing you pretty much can't get around. There is https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki however that simplifies similar things via annotations.

Comment: @zapl annotations can be used in some kind of proxy parent class, so it would be an solution, could you post it as an answer with example, how to apply it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid specifically of some `super.theMethodIAmIn()` calls, you can in fact do it very similar to the "even better" case if you do those super calls inside a class that you extend:

```
public class BetterActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        onCreateNoSuper(savedInstanceState);
    }
    // could be abstract as well.
    protected void onCreateNoSuper(Bundle savedInstanceState) {}
}
```

now you can do

```
class MyActivity extends BetterActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreateNoSuper(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // done.
    }
}
```

Drawbacks:

- you have to use a different method name.
- slight change in semantics can lead to problems if someone calls those derived (`onCreateNoSuper`) methods directly instead of calling `onCreate`. Should not happen with Android's `onSomethingHappened` methods since only the system calls them.
- if you extend `MyActivity` again you have to call `super` again or use the same trick again.

A very similar approach should work via Annotations. For example [Android Annotations#HowItWorks](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/HowItWorks) is an example of creating a sub class dynamically via Java's annotation processor at compile time.

You could for example write your code like

```
class MySpecialActivity extends Activity {
    @OnCreate
    protected void randomlyNamed(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // done.
    }
}
```

And the annotation processor would generate

```
class MySpecialActivity_ extends MySpecialActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        randomlyNamed(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Drawbacks here:

- you need to write rather complex code to generate a `.java` file dynamically.
- you need to configure your build environment to run the annotation processor.
- you need to use that generated subclass instead of your class in several places.
- you don't even save a line of code since you replace the super call with some `@OnCreate` annotation.

Going one step further you might be able to physically insert the super call into the method by modifying the compiled bytecode (see e.g. [ASM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ObjectWeb_ASM)). You would still need to configure your build environment to do that step but now you could really do what you wrote in your "even better" case. Write code as usual and your post-compiler simply adds those pesky calls if you forgot them.

That's also what proguard does. It inspects the bytecode, optimize & obfuscate it before Android's dex compiler will transform the result into android's dex format.